# Does opera mobile support scrollable divs?

Tags: css, opera, mobile-website, opera-mobile

I am trying to add a scrollable grid to a mobile web site I am currently working on. I've tried using the [jQuery Scrollable Table Plugin](http://farinspace.com/jquery-scrollable-table-plugin/) written by [farinspace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97433/farinspace), which works fine in IE8 but doesn't work at all in [Opera Mobile for Windows](http://labs.opera.com/news/2010/04/22/). I've also tried using the Telerik MVC Grid extension, and that also will not give me a scrollable grid.

So, before I give up on the idea and switch to using a paging grid, has anyone ever got anything like this working on Opera Mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually gave up on this, as I don't think it would have worked very well at all. Just not a very nice user experience.

What I've gone with is to display the table in it's entirety with no scrolling or paging enabled. So, I am relying purely on the scrolling capability of the browser.

It seems to work really nicely on my blackberry and I think will be nice to use on a touch smart phone too, as the user can just swipe their thumb/finger to scroll down and check the list. Then just swipe back to the top of the list to press the relevant button.

Actually, thinking about it, i might provide a "back to top" link under the grid :)

Comment: Good move. Multiple scroll bars on a small screen can make a really tricky user experience ;).

Comment: it's definitely a case of "less is more" where small screens are concerned.